# How to create pagination using anfularfire2/firestore

Tags: angular, pagination, angularfire2

I'm trying to create a pagination and I want to query items with offset and limit that is passed dynamic (when clicked in the UI).
I'm using collection. Is there any way to query data starting from index and limit for example 5 items?

I'm trying the following:

```js
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore'; 
//other code

public getData(offsetFrom, offsetTo) { 
  this.fromQuery$ = this.db.collection('transactions', (ref) => ( 
  ref.where('fromAddress', '==', this.fromAddress)
  .orderBy('date', 'asc')
  // I want to start from item number, but maybe not possible using angularfirestore
  // where startAt accepts param - field value 
  .startAt(3).limit(2))).valueChanges(); 
}
```

I don't want to select all items because they may be a lot and I want to load for example 5 items on click of the next/ previous items button.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to start from index. You have to use `DocumentSnapshot` and `startAt` function. Ex

```js
public getData(doc: DocumentSnapshot, limit) { 
  this.fromQuery$ = this.db.collection('transactions', (ref) => ( 
  ref.where('fromAddress', '==', this.fromAddress)
  .orderBy('date', 'asc')
  .startAt(doc).limit(limit))).valueChanges(); 
}
```

You can find something similar at official documentation https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/infinite-scroll-firestore-angular/